# How to get xunit test method name in base class even before the control goes to the method?

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I want to find the test method name in the base class.

Here is my use case

```
public class TestClass : Base
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestMehthod()
    {
    }
}

public class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test method name is "+); // how to get test method     name here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read this first? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        string methodName = this.GetType().GetMethods()
                                          .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes<FactAttribute>().Any())
                                          .Select(m => m.Name)
                                          .FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine("Test method name is " + methodName); // how to get test method     name here.
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

xUnit has concept of attribute hooks which are running before and after test.
If you want to know name of the method when you run it - you could create your attribute which would output it to console:

```
public class MethodNameToConsoleAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{
    public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test method name is " + methodUnderTest.Name);
    }
}
```

and then put it on your base class:

```
[MethodNameToConsole]
public class Base
{
   ...
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Ok, now I see what you want to achieve.
I must say that currently xUnit doesn't provide any normal way to do it. However it has other concept called `ITestOutputHelper` which allows you to add your output to xUnit's. In version 2 xUnit team has only one implementation of this interface, called [TestOutputHelper](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/1d568d7a5a2884a3d74b5b28b127ad3525e2122c/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/TestOutputHelper.cs) and it contains a private field of type ITest.

In this particular case we can make a hack retrieving a private member and then test method name from it. It would look like this:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        var helper = (TestOutputHelper)testOutputHelper;

        ITest test = (ITest)helper.GetType().GetField("test", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                  .GetValue(helper);

        testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Test method name is " + test.TestCase.TestMethod.Method.Name);
    }
}
```

**BUT** I wouldn't recommend you to lay down on it because it's details of implementation which may change in the future.

I would rather create an issue on Github specifying this particular case you require. [xUnit](https://github.com/xunit/xunit) is open-source project and you can feel free to write to its developers.

Comment: This would give me any test method in that particular class. I want the test method name that i am currently running. Thanks for the help. In MSTest case, it is set though test context. I wonder at what stage textcontext is being initialized and how does it get the test name.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Oleksii Aza, but the Before() method will be called after the base class constructor gets executed. So i still have the problem of accessing the test name in the base class constructor. I can not clearly give my use case here, but the gist of it is to access the name in the base class constructor

Comment: @vijayinvites Hello again, wrote an addition on your topic, hope it helps with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Xunit Test class Constructor, and injecting it with an `ITestOutputHelper` could help you extract the test method name before the code run. Weirdly looking at first, this test class constructor would run on before each test method and you can use it to prepare your assets and also to use the test output if you inject the `ITestOutputHelper` (No other registration needed).

On your test class constructor, you can do something like that add the test method name as a class member (It will be new for each test method...)

On other note Console.Writeline() would not work in Xuint context, but you can use the same helper weve injected for that!

```
public class TestClass : Base
{
    public TestClass(ITestOutputHelper helper):Base(helper)
    {
    }
}
...

public class Base
{
    public Base(ITestOutputHelper helper)
    {
        var type = helper.GetType();
        var testMember = type.GetField("test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var testMethodName = ((ITest)testMember.GetValue(helper)).DisplayName;
        helper.WriteLine("Test method name is "+testMethodName);
//
    }
}
```

If you need the test method in more then one place, you can create an ITestOutputHelper Extension method and use it on the object it self:

```
        public static string GetTestName(this ITestOutputHelper helper)
        {
            var type = helper.GetType();
            var testMember = type.GetField("test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            return ((ITest)testMember.GetValue(helper)).DisplayName;
        }
```

And then call the `helper.GetTestName()`